# Google Drive APIs Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

When I want to "Google Drive APIs" authentication, I should be able to access my e-mail and password for users to approve, without these it is impossible to be connected.
Is there a solution that could be provided without putting the my privacy of email users access the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid getting the `"email and profile"` scopes from user and just ask `"drive"` scope for your application. If you do so, then user's email address wont be accessible for you but you can create/modify all the files from the user's Drive.

If your are confused with the authentication process - User in any case, never share their google password to you. Because the authentication is taken care by google and in response you will only get an access token after successful authentication.

Have a look at these links.

**OAuth:** 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

**Scopes:** https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes